# Why is the "edit" link missing from the user profile page on Meta?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, profile-page

Obviously it's not missing from *this* Meta, but it is on the [Meta of MartialArts.SE](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/).

It's not just an idiosyncracy of the themes being used for this beta site, it also appears to be the the case on other SE sites.

Is there any reason for this? Why must I go to the main SE site to edit my profile, why can't I do it from the site's Meta as well?

Edit: I forgot to add the screen shots, first is the main site, second is the Meta:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why exactly is this feature request? What are you requesting here?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I thought I had explained it well enough... I've got no issues with the profile being identical between a site and its meta, but the meta should have the edit link too. Clearly it isn't a bug, therefore by definition it has to be a feature request, albeit not the biggest ever. I needed to change my profile after inadvertantly copying it across all sites, I had to hunt round to find how to change it - not the best UX.

Comment: **the meta should have the edit link too** - this part is missing in your post. :)

Comment: Chiming in here because I just noticed this. This seems like a UX oversight. I understand the profiles are linked, but I believe the "Edit" link should still show up on Meta for consistency sake. Just take the user to the edit form on the main site, but just don't hide the link. I seriously thought for a few moments that I somehow had been signed out of the site and didn't have permission to edit my profile because of that.

Answer (score 6):

Per site Metas profiles are tied to the main site profile, same as with Meta reputation. MSO is the exception, the only one, mostly for historical reasons.

Comment: IIRC the main reason is so that non-SO users aren't disadvantaged when it comes to discussing network-wide issues. Hopefully the team will roll out MSE soon :\

Comment: @ManishEarthwantsmorewaffles As I said, historical reasons: A bad decision that was taken some time ago, and we still haven't fixed it.

Comment: Yep, I get that, and it is part of my point - why is the edit link (and only the edit link) missing from the meta? Surely I should be able to edit my profile on that site from either the main or the meta? (Not that it's a huge deal, just an inconsistency I noticed).

Comment: Oh, right. The decision to make MSO==MSE. My bad :P

Comment: @slugster Constructing the edit link via URL manipulation redirects back to the profile--which means that this was a conscious decision made some time.

Comment: I don't believe it was a bad decision at the time. I think it just *evolved* to the point where we outgrew the concept of MSO with the onslaught of the SE 2.0 sites.

Comment: @slugster Ah, I see your point. Well, I guess there could be an edit link there, point to the main profile edit page.