# Edit profile on Meta Islam.SE

Tags: support, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the “edit” link missing from the user profile page on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137371/why-is-the-edit-link-missing-from-the-user-profile-page-on-meta)

I wanted to keep a different description of myself on [Islam.SE](http://islam.stackexchange.com) and it's [meta](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com). I see a edit link on my profile page for the main site which I have edited and added a different description, but not for the meta site.

Can anyone please let me know, why I am not able to edit the profile on meta Islam.SE? Is it synced with the main SE site?

Also, please let me know, which is the proper site to ask such questions? I mean, this is something technical and not related to the community of the concerned SE site. I thought, this would best belong to meta.SO, so asked the question here.

Comment: Besides this main Meta, the meta sites are "satellites" of the main sites and users don't have their own profile on them.

Comment: You're right about the site, meta.SO is the historical place to ask questions about technical issues with the SE sites.

Comment: Hmm, I now understand this completely. [metase] is a full fledged SO child site but dedicated to just the main SO. And all other [se] sites have meta's as satellites as mentioned by @ShaWizDowArd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your per site Meta profile is linked to your main site profile, unfortunately there isn't a way to have a different profile on a per site Meta. The only Meta that you can have a different profile is Meta Stack Overflow, but that's because it's a bit special, it doubles as the Meta for Stack Overflow and the Meta for the entire Stack Exchange network.

As for your second question, it would be absolutely fine if you have asked this on Meta Islam, regardless of the question being about a technical issue. It might even be preferable to ask all your Meta questions on your site's Meta instead of Meta Stack Overflow, per site Metas need all the love they can get and a healthy and active Meta is a sign of a healthy and active community.

Comment: What is confusing though is that there still is a "click here to edit" link on the meta page, and it does nothing besides refreshing the page.

Comment: @Gnoupi Hm? There's no edit link on a per site Meta profile.

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I see the problem. It's not an edit link, it's the "click here to edit", probably because I have a blank "about me". I'll make a bug report about this (though it's quite minor)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144178/remove-the-click-here-to-edit-link-on-a-meta-profile