# Remove the "click here to edit" link on a Meta profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, per-site-meta

When the "about me" section is empty, it contains the following:

> (your about me is currently blank)
>
> [click here to edit](http://example.com)

[Meta profiles can't be edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137371/why-is-the-edit-link-missing-from-the-user-profile-page-on-meta), and the "edit" link is removed from them. But if you happen to have an empty "about me" section, this other link will still be visible (and it does nothing besides refreshing the page).

So it would probably be a good idea to remove it, the same way the edit link is removed.

Comment: That explains why I suddenly got a comment on an old question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A while back we changed the edit link to go to the master site's edit page so you are able to directly edit your profile.  This question never got updated when that change was deployed though, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

According to [the answer to that question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137371/why-is-the-edit-link-missing-from-the-user-profile-page-on-meta/137373#137373), "Per site Metas profiles are tied to the main site profile, same as with Meta reputation."

It might instead make sense to keep the edit link, but have it link to the editing interface *on the main site*. That would also cause the meta profile to change, as the user expects.